# How to plot multiple columns side by side with Seaborn countplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I have a `Pandas DataFrame`, for example:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    "A": [165,166,920,920,920,165,162,162,166,165,755,469],
    "B": [1920,868,470,470,698,945,1670,575,701,1920,1920,470],
    "C": [1670,461,461,212,212,212,212,414,453,196,254,461]
})
```

I would like to have a `seaborn countplot` of each `option A, B and C` with the `top 2` for each column plotted side by side.

Below is an image of something similar. My problem is getting the columns side by side with the legend.

[image: Something similar to this]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df=pd.DataFrame({
"A": [165,166,920,920,920,165,162,162,166,165,755,469],
"B": [1920,868,470,470,698,945,1670,575,701,1920,1920,470],
"C": [1670,461,461,212,212,212,212,414,453,196,254,461]})


sns.set(style="darkgrid")
fig, ax =plt.subplots(3,1)
max_count = max([max(df[i].value_counts()) for i in df.columns])
A=sns.countplot(y=df['A'],ax=ax[0],order=df.A.value_counts().iloc[:2].index)
B=sns.countplot(y=df['B'],ax=ax[1],order=df.B.value_counts().iloc[:2].index)
C=sns.countplot(y=df['C'],ax=ax[2],order=df.C.value_counts().iloc[:2].index)
ax[0].set_xlim(0,max_count)
ax[1].set_xlim(0,max_count)
ax[2].set_xlim(0,max_count)
A.set(xticklabels=[])
B.set(xticklabels=[])
```

[image]

Comment: How can I set the overall title. Set and set_title does not work

Comment: @A.JT, use this: `ax[0].set_title(<title>)` Let me know if this works for you. :)

Comment: Happy to have helped you, @A.JT! :)